# Issue Running Functional Tests with dbt-adapters in dbt-core Project

Tags: python-venv, dbt

I'm encountering an issue while running functional tests in the dbt-core project after making changes to the dbt-adapters project. Here's the rundown:

1. I've made modifications to the dbt-adapters project.
2. I've set up a shared virtual environment for both the dbt-adapters and dbt-core projects.
3. I've installed the development requirements using pip install -r dev-requirements.txt and installed dbt-adapters as editable.
4. When trying to run a functional test with `python3 -m pytest tests/functional/simple_snapshot`, I faced the following error:

```
ImportError: Error importing plugin "dbt.tests.fixtures.project": No module named 'dbt.tests.fixtures'
```

I'm struggling to pinpoint the cause of this error. Could you offer any guidance on resolving it? Also, I'd appreciate any advice or best practices for setting up a testing environment for dbt projects and smoothly running functional tests across different dbt projects.